# BlobstoreService.getUploads always returns NULL

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, servlets, blobstore

I'm trying to store an image to the Google Appengine Blobstore from an android device. What I've done so far:

- Created an Enpoint (Google Cloud Endpoints) that returns an upload URL (Working)
- Created a POST request with OKHTTP3 that sends the image file in a multipartform (Working? Maybe not?)
- Created a Servlet that is passed to the upload URL to handle getting the keys. (It gets called, but getUpload always returns null.)

I'm thinking maybe it has to do with how I'm sending my POST request?

```
 OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

    RequestBody body = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
            .addPart(
                    Headers.of("Content-Disposition", "form-data; name=\"photo\""),
                    RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), file)
            )

            .build();

    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(url)
            .post(body)
            .build();
```

In my Servlet I can see a param named "photo"  but calling:

```
List<BlobKey> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploads(req).get("photo");
```

returns null. Zero BlobKeys...

I'm sure I'm missing something dumb... Any help would be incredibly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

So in the end it WAS the POST request.

```
RequestBody body = new MultipartBody.Builder()
        .setType(MultipartBody.FORM)
        .addFormData("photo", "photoname")
        .addFormData("photo", "photo.jpg", RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpeg"), file)
        .build();
```